# Replacing and removing parts of a string

Tags: php

I have a string made up from a URL like so: `http://www.foo.com/parentfoo/childfoo/` and I want to turn it into `http://www.foo.com/parentfoo#childfoo`

What's the best way to remove the last two ' / ' and replace the second to last ' / ' with ' # '?

Comment: PHP Shell - http://3v4l.org/mXGHR

Comment: @Tom, I updated my answer with a little bit more explanation. Hopefully it will make it a little more clear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `regex` to find the last `/`.

```
<?php
$url =  'http://www.foo.com/parentfoo/childfoo/';
$output = preg_replace('!/([^/]+)/$!', "/#\\1", $url);
echo $output."\n";
?>
```

Here's a little bit of explanation of how this works.

1. First, we delimit the regex using `!` instead of the usual `/` because we are trying to match against `/` inside the expression, which saves us certain amount of confusion and headache with escaping the `/`.
2. The expression `/([^/]+)/$`. We are matching a literal `/`, followed by some nonzero number of non-`/` characters, followed by another literal `/`, followed by the end of string `$`. By tying the match to the end of string, we ensure that the two literal `/` we have matched are exactly the last and second-to-last `/` in the input.
3. The grouping parenthesis `()` captures the expression in between the two `/`, and the replacement expression `\1` substitutes it back in during the replacement.

Comment: The land of regex... I'll never understand it yet it's so beautiful. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Last Slash first and then Replace the Last Slash with a Hash

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.foo.com/parentfoo/childfoo/";

$url = substr($url, 0, -1);

$add = "#";

$new =  preg_replace("~\/(?!.*\/)~", $add, $url);

echo $new;
?>
```

**Output**

```
http://www.foo.com/parentfoo#childfoo
```

Comment: This is great! I started reading up on SEO as I posted this and I think I want to keep the second / to make /# instead but thank you anyways for this. Now I think I understand preg_replace a bit more.

Comment: No problem, just change the --- $add = "#";  --- to -- $add = "/#";

Answer (score 0):

First, find the last position:

```
$url = "http://www.foo.com/parentfoo/childfoo/";
$last = strrpos($url, '/');
if ($last === false) {
   return false;
}
```

From there, find the 2nd last:

```
$next_to_last = strrpos($url, '/', $last - strlen($url) - 1);

$var1  = substr_replace($url,"",$last);
echo $var2  = substr_replace($var1, "#", $next_to_last, 1);   
//  http://www.foo.com/parentfoo#childfoo
```